# UX between app and Website

Tags: gui-design, ux-field, users, user-journey

We currently have an app with certain features such as Timesheets and Booking holiday which is fundamental to our workers.

However we also have a live website which has all the other content that is relevant to our users such as internal News etc

The task is to bridge the gap between the two platforms

So my question is this - is there an generic approach for a UX, navigationing features between the app and Website, or is this just a big no no? Until we have the app developed?

And also each platform requires a seperate log in to make it an even uglier UX

I cant see how this will work unless its app > app or Website > website?

Any advice on this or reasons to push back on this would be greatly appreciated, as i have not come up against someting like this before..

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to have a different approach as this is simply expanding the scope of your inquiry into multiple channels (and devices), and thus broadening the definition of your digital ecosystem.

Answer (score 2):

My question would be, why can't the features like Timesheets and Booking holiday be on the website as well? And vice versa, why can't the Internet news, etc. be in the app? Why do there need to be two different platforms?

Having two places to work sounds very annoying for your users.
Having one or both applications have the same features would be ideal I guess in your situation.

The question normally is, do we need a website or an app. In which the answer often lies in what you want to achieve (can I build what I want with the technology) or how frequently the user uses your app (a user is not likely to download a native app they'll only use a few times a year) or where the user is using it (like where a whole time tracking and billing service has a web application but also has a native timer app for tracking time while on the go as sort of a companion app).

If development overhead (the time and money spent on maintaining two different code bases for the two different applications) is an issue you could look into

- choosing just one of the platforms (native app or web application) and build the missing features into that
- a shared code base (there are possibilities to create a native app with web technologies which can be build with one and the same codebase which prevents having to spent more time and money maintaining two different code bases)

A fast solution would be to add the news stuff from the website in the native app by way of webviews.

I hope this is of any help to you.

Comment: Thank you for the help here Paul. The issue is that we do currently have a new version of Timesheets and Booking holiday features on the website, but these are all rebranded and extra functionality, and so we are not trying to push all the current users on this new platform, but drip feed them through, as it will cause chaos trying to support these users. So for now we are just trying to redirect them over gradually, but just feel its such an ugly UX, and feel this should be pushed back.

Answer (score 0):

It's not uncommon to have products which exist on a website and not in the mobile app and vice versa.

Recently examples I've seen recently:

- Natwest mobile app > natwest rewards website, requires separate login and accounts
- Spotify - certain features not available on the mobile app

It's 100% a poorer user experience than everything being on one platform, but it's not always possible to do everything at once.

Context switching, navigational errors, increased cognitive load in terms of remembering multiple accounts, frustrations around feature expectations not being met when in one platform or another could all occur.

Large organisations will often migrate features in parts and need to, for either budget or timescale reasons.

You could look into the approaches advocated in general web development in terms of mobile first design and specifically progressive enhancement / enrichment.

I'd suggest being really clear why people might change platform, what the reason is and provide easy routes to get back (recover) would be sensible.